# SIGINT handler reset in Visual C++ 2015

Tags: c++, signals

Consider the following test program

```
#include <csignal>
#include <iostream>

volatile std::sig_atomic_t signal_raised = 0;

void set_signal_raised(int signal) {
    signal_raised = 1;
}

void check(std::sig_atomic_t expected) {
    if (signal_raised != expected) {
        std::cerr << signal_raised << " != " << expected << std::endl;
        abort();
    }
}

int main() {
    using namespace std;
    check(0);
    std::signal(SIGINT, set_signal_raised);
    check(0);
    std::raise(SIGINT);
    check(1);
    signal_raised = 0;
    check(0);
    std::raise(SIGINT);
    check(1);
    cerr << "OK.\n";
}
```

With GCC and Clang, it outputs "OK." However, with Visual Studio 2015, it outputs nothing.

The signal handler is reset after handling the first signal. This can be verified by adding

```
auto prev = std::signal(SIGINT, set_signal_raised);
if (prev != set_signal_raised) {
    std::cerr << "Unexpected handler." << std::endl;
    abort();
}
```

to the check function. Is this allowed and expected?

Comment: I can't see anything in C11 allowing VS's behaviour. It doesn't go out of its way to prohibit it, though, either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reset of the signal disposition is the behaviour that Unix System V used. But the BSD (currently glibc) do not reset the signal disposition. Either behaviour is allowed by POSIX standard allowed. C standard doesn't specify whether the "reset" is allowed.

From [`signal(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/signal.2.html):

> POSIX.1 solved the portability mess by specifying sigaction(2), which
>          provides explicit control of the semantics when a signal handler is
>          invoked; use that interface instead of signal().
>
> In the original UNIX systems, when a handler that was established
>          using signal() was invoked by the delivery of a signal, the
>          disposition of the signal would be reset to SIG_DFL, and the system
>          did not block delivery of further instances of the signal.  This is
>          equivalent to calling sigaction(2) with the following flags:
>
> sa.sa_flags = SA_RESETHAND | SA_NODEFER;
>
> System V also provides these semantics for signal().  This was bad
>          because the signal might be delivered again before the handler had a
>          chance to reestablish itself.  Furthermore, rapid deliveries of the
>          same signal could result in recursive invocations of the handler.

So, it seems Visual studio follows the System V behaviour.

> Is this allowed and expected?

It's allowed but certainly not desired. For this reason, POSIX introduced [`sigaction()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sigaction.html). If you have `sigaction()` then use it.
Otherwise, you just need to reinstall the handler everytime inside the signal handler:

```
void set_signal_raised(int signal) {
    std::signal(SIGINT, set_signal_raised);
    signal_raised = 1;
}
```

Comment: Great! Just to be clear for anyone else reading this in the future: Reinstalling the current signal is allowed in handlers. (In general, almost nothing is allowed in handlers.) http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/signal